# Calculate new (78) variables based on column input from 78*2 other variables dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to make a simple subtraction based on a "two column" pair, the a1...n and c1...n series to create a third column b1...n over 78 "pairs" in dplyr. But, I do not know how to call the columns correctly and rund it over each column pair.

```
df
var C400.0   C403.7  C407.1  A399.6  A403.4   A406.4
V1  1.176    1.149   1.111   0.767   0.736    0.699
V2  1.192    1.160   1.127   0.770   0.738    0.707
V3  1.223    1.1918  1.154   0.775   0.744    0.715
```

I have tried:

```
b_names <- c( "B400",   "B403",   "B407")
df_b  <- mutate_at(df,vars(C400.0:C407.1), .funs(b_names= ., vars(C400.0:C407.1)-vars(A399.6:A403.4)))
```

with no success

The results should look like

```
df_b
var C400.0   C403.7  C407.1  A399.6  A403.4   A406.4 B400   B403   B407
V1  1.176    1.149   1.111   0.767   0.736    0.699  0.408  0.412  0.412
V2  1.192    1.160   1.127   0.770   0.738    0.707  0.421  0.421  0.420
V3  1.223    1.1918  1.154   0.775   0.744    0.715  0.447  0.447  0.439
```

Comment: Get your data in long format without values encoded in column names. `tidyr::gather` or `reshape2::melt` will help with that.

Comment: Or, just work positionally in base: `cbind(df, setNames(df[2:4] - df[5:7], b_names))`. Make sure everything is in the right order first.

Comment: I guess reshape2 and tidyr don't melt multiple columns..? With data.table you could use the patterns helper function `data.table(df) %>% melt(meas=patterns("A", "C"), value.name=c("A","C")) %>% mutate(B = C - A)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution based on first tidying your data into long format.

```
# load packages
require(stringr)
require(tidyverse)

# your example data
df <- read_table('var C400.0   C403.7  C407.1  A399.6  A403.4   A406.4
V1  1.176    1.149   1.111   0.767   0.736    0.699
V2  1.192    1.160   1.127   0.770   0.738    0.707
V3  1.223    1.1918  1.154   0.775   0.744    0.715')

# generating obtained values
df %>%
    gather(col, value, -var) %>%
    mutate(col_letter = str_extract(col, 'A|C')) %>%
    group_by(var, col_letter) %>%
    mutate(col_position = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(var) %>%
    select(-col) %>%
    spread(col_letter, value) %>%
    mutate(dif = C - A) %>%
    select(var, col_position, dif) %>%
    spread(col_position, dif, sep='_') %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)
```

This doesn't get the column names you want in the output, but it does contain all the values you asked for.  You could manually rename at this point if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't use `dplyr` but accomplishes what you want.

```
library(readr)
df <- read_table('var C400.0   C403.7  C407.1  A399.6  A403.4   A406.4
V1  1.176    1.149   1.111   0.767   0.736    0.699
V2  1.192    1.160   1.127   0.770   0.738    0.707
V3  1.223    1.1918  1.154   0.775   0.744    0.715')
```

**No Nasty Side Effects Version (also not looping, all vectorized)**

This is thanks to Gregor.  I don't mind side effects when I make them intentionally, but not everybody feels the same way :)

```R
library(stringr)
cNames = grep("^C",names(df),value=T)
aNames = grep("^A",names(df),value=T)

newCols = df[cNames]-df[aNames]
setNames(newCols, paste0("B", str_extract(cNames, "[0-9]+")))
#Alternative solution that doesn't require the stringr library
#setNames(newCols, paste0("B", sub(".*?([0-9]+).*","\\1",cNames)))
df = cbind(df,newCols)
```

First we extract the 'C' names and the 'A' names.  This assumes they're already in order, but the results you showed in your question don't make it clear how A406.4 was matched to C403.7.

Then we can subset df based on column names and do element-wise subtraction of the resulting subset data.frames.  We change the names and do a simple `cbind`.

**Original Solution**

```R
mapply(function(x,y){
  num = str_extract(x,"[0-9]+") 
  df[[paste0("B",num)]] = df[[x]]-df[[y]] 
  assign("df",df,envir=globalenv()) 
  return(NULL) 
},cNames,aNames)
```

Then I wrote a function which takes two inputs and used `mapply` to loop across the set of 'C' names and 'A' names.  At each combination we extract the numbers of the 'C' name and paste that onto a 'B' and assign it the difference of 'C'-'A'.  Then, because we're building up a set of new columns, I assign the resulting `df` back to the global environment (big old side effect).  mapply returns a bunch of NULLs but df has been updated to include your B columns.  This preserves your original wide data structure just without using the `tidyverse`

Comment: Instead of your `mapply` and `assign`, you could just do `new_cols = df[cNames] - df[aNames]`, set the names all at once `setNames(new_cols, paste0("B", str_extract(cNames, "[0-9]+")))`,  and finally `result = cbind(df, new_cols)`. No loops/apply needed, all vectorized, and no nasty side effects.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks. Clearly I hadn't thought of that - added your vectorised solution.

Comment: One other (minor) suggestion - since you're already `grep` for the `aNames` and `cNames`, you could kill the `stringr` dependency entirely by also using `grep` instead of `str_extract` for the new column names.

Comment: Unless I'm way off base, `grep` with `value=T` returns the whole string if it matches the search pattern, not just the matched portion. `sub` can be used if the regex is modified and `regexpr` can give info to run a `substr` but none of them are as 'nice' as `stringr`.  I'll add in a `sub` alternative as an example.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I used a toy example with numbers 1:10 and thought the `grep` output matching elements 1:10 was actually extracting the 1:10 from my strings.